# BlackBerry 10 Twitter Integration

Tags: twitter, blackberry-10

I would like to integrate Twitter into my BlackBerry 10 application so that I can post, get, favorite and retweet messages from Twitter. Native BlackBerry.

Comment: I think you might want to elaborate as to which development approach you are taking (e.g. HTML5, Native, AIR, etc) as well as what you've tried and what problems you are having.

Comment: @Doug Sorry, I've edited it. It's Native.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching on github - there are several sample twitter projects on there:
[Github search results](https://github.com/search?q=twitter%20blackberry%2010&type=Repositories&ref=simplesearch)

For example: [BB10 Sample Twitter App](https://github.com/kylefowler/twitter-bb10)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, BB10 platform offers built-in [invocation requests for a core Twitter app](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/invocation/twitter.html), however, these requests are pretty limited in functionality - you can only share content with different URI, but not get, favourite, retweet message and so on.

If there's another application which can handle these type of requests, you may use unbound (or bound) requests for you needs, but in order to do that you have to know `Action` attribute (and `TargetID` in case of bound invocations) value.

Here is a link explaining mechanism of invocation sending as well as bound and unbound requests - https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/invocation/sending_invocation.html